# Elasticsearch nested query over mapped DynamoDb data returns nothing

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, dsl

I have mapped data from DynamoDb in Elasticsearch. I want to return a document querying it by nested data. And I have a problem with the simplest nested query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "doc.dynamodb.newImage.childCalls.M",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "doc.dynamodb.newImage.childCalls.M.caller.S": "+18002427338"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "doc.dynamodb.newImage.childCalls.M.callee.S": "+18002427338"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Looks like I missed something essential. And here is the mapping:

```
"childCalls": {
    "properties": {
        "M": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
                "callee": {
                    "properties": {
                        "S": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "caller": {
                    "properties": {
                        "S": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "index": "not_analyzed"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response doesn't contain any error:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [

    ]
  }
}
```

And yes, index contains the document I wan't to return. Also I tried `caller.S` path and it didn't help.

**UPD**

It seems nested data should be a `{key: value}` object to get indexed properly. Thus I need a pipeline of preprocessors to transform values represented with objects into a plane values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a couple of days it has occurred that nested mapping is not necessary at all when array of objects consists of objects which do not look like `{key: string|number|boolean}`. Complex objects are not transformed as it is described in [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/nested.html), they looks like array of objects. And here is the mappings:

```
"childCalls": {
    "properties": {
        "L": {
            "properties": {
                "M": {
                    "properties": {
                        "callee": {
                            "properties": {
                                "S": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "caller": {
                            "properties": {
                                "S": {
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and working query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "doc.dynamodb.newImage.childCalls.L.M.caller.S": "+18002427338"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "doc.dynamodb.newImage.childCalls.L.M.callee.S": "+18002427338"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```